# Min value while ignoring zeros

Tags: excel, vba

Is there another way to get the smallest values, while ignoring the 0s, out of the `Instr` i show in the code below? I tried to use `If` a couple of times in order to get the smallest value but it does not work everytime because if the first two lines (letters) are empty or equals to 0 the rest of the `If` will always be 0. I also tried to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min` but didn't manage to find a way in vba to include a condition to ignore the 0s.

```
    If carater = "d" Then
    str_f = str_f & str_var
        b = InStr(1, Mid(cel, 1, 999), "/", vbTextCompare) 'cel = (dAA11b+dAA12b)/dAA13b*100
        c = InStr(1, Mid(cel, 1, 999), "*", vbTextCompare)
        d = InStr(1, Mid(cel, 1, 999), "-", vbTextCompare)
        e = InStr(1, Mid(cel, 1, 999), "+", vbTextCompare)
        f = InStr(1, Mid(cel, 1, 999), ")", vbTextCompare)

        minimo = 0
        If b <> 0 Then
        minimo = b
        End If

        'test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min

        If c <> 0 And c < minimo Then
        minimo = c
        End If

        If d <> 0 And d < minimo Then
        minimo = d
        End If

        If e <> 0 And e < minimo Then
        minimo = e
        End If

        If f <> 0 And f < minimo Then
        minimo = f
        End If

        'a = Mid(cel, i, minimo - 2)
        'str_f = str_f & a & str_var1
        '.Cells(567, 3).Value = str_f

    End If
```

Comment: You can replace 0's in your range with blanks which will be ignored by the `Min` function.

Comment: Yes but in this situation that can't be applied because I'm not getting the values from any column or row but from a ```Instr``` that tells me the character position of a certain text formula.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but it looks as if you're trying to find the first occurrence of a character that exists in a list. A common way of doing this is to iterate each character in your string and test if it exists within the list. As soon as you've found a match, you can exit the routine with the found index value. Code would look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim result As Long

    result = firstOccurence(Sheet1.Range("A1"))

    If result = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No operator found."
    Else
        MsgBox "Operator found at " & result
    End If

End Sub

Private Function firstOccurence( _
    cellToTest As Range, _
    Optional oprSet As String = "/*-+)") As Long

    Dim chrSet As String, chr As String, opr As String
    Dim c As Long, o As Long

    'You should sense check the parameters here.

    ' ...

    'Test if each character of the string to be tested
    'exists in the operator list.
    'As soon as one is found, exit the function.
    chrSet = cellToTest.Value2

    For c = 1 To Len(chrSet) 'the test string
        chr = Mid(chrSet, c, 1)
        For o = 1 To Len(oprSet) 'the operator list
            opr = Mid(oprSet, o, 1)
            If chr = opr Then 'found one!
                firstOccurence = c
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Nothing found so function returns 0.

End Function
```

Comment: I have a vast list of text formulas stored in one column (e.g. ```(dAA11b+dAA12b)/dAA13b*100)```) and what I'm trying to do is convert these text formulas into proper excel formulas in another column. For example everytime the character is "d" it will insert a string ```"VLOOKUP("""``` before the letter "d" and after that it loops until it finds a character = to "+", "-", "*" or "/"... after doing this gathers the code before that character (e.g. dAA11b before the "+") and inserts that after the ```vlookup``` string and also inserts the next string (...)

Comment: (...) ```""";Variáveis;MATCH(F1;Variáveis!$A$1:$AD$1;0);FALSE)"``` (as represented by the last 3 lines of comentary in the code i posted above).

Comment: I think your best bet would be to articulate all of that in a new question (or edit this one with a full re-write). Give some sample data and explain what code you have so far is doing and what doesn't work as you wish it to. Your current question is too unclear for people to respond effectively.